# NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to list my Sushis and I have: `Name, Price, Type of Sushi` to list. The problem is I need to show the `Type of Sushi` by name and not by id. I tried to put `<%= sushi.tipo_sushi.name %>` before `<%= sushi.tipo_sushi_id %>` but I got this message when I put `rails s` in cmd: `undefined method "name" for nil:NilClass` (that's not listed when I use `<%= sushi.tipo_sushi_id %>`.

*/app/views/sushis/index.html.erb:*

```
<% @sushis.each do |sushi| %>
    <%= sushi.name %>
    <%= sushi.price %>
    <%= sushi.tipo_sushi.name %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', sushi %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sushi_path(sushi) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', sushi, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

app/models/sushi.rb:

```
class Sushi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tipo_sushi, class_name: SushiTipo
end
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Well the problem here is that if you check in the database, one of the `sushi` records does not have a `tipo_sushi` association, `sushi.tipo_sushi` is basically `nil`.

Comment: I think you should inform yourself about associations, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: PNY, thank you, man!! The problem was in DB like you said!

Answer (score 0):

Type in `rails c` in your command line and then type

```
TipoSushi.attribute_names
```

You will be presented with an array of attributes and column names belonging to your `TipoSushi` table.

If `TipoSushi.attribute_names.include?(:name)` returns `false`, then that means there is no such column in your table.

You then need to run a migration

```
rails g migration AddNameToTipoSushi name: string
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then make sure in your model, you validate all the fields

```
class TipoSushi
  validates :name, :price, :presence => true
```